# jQuery Running a removeClass/addClass function to a child

Tags: jquery, addclass, children

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".drop-box").click(function() {
    $(".drop-box:eq(2)").removeClass("contracted contract");
    $(".drop-box:eq(2)").addClass("drop");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".drop-box").click(function() {
    $(".drop-box:eq(2)").removeClass("drop");
    $(".drop-box:eq(2)").addClass("contract");
  });
});
```

```css
.drop-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px
}
.drop-box-title {} .drop-image-box {
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.image-box-text,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
.contracted {
  height: 0px
}
@-webkit-keyframes drop {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
.drop {
  height: auto;
  -webkit-animation-name: drop;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-name: drop;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes contract {
  0% {
    height: 300px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0px;
  }
}
.contract {
  height: 0px;
  -webkit-animation-name: contract;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-name: contract;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="drop-box">
    <div class="drop-box-title">
      <h2>Image Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="drop-image-box contracted">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="drop-box-description">
      <p class="image-box-text">A breif Description of the image</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Hi I'm trying to create some expanding image boxes in jQuery using addClass and removeclass. (Theres probably an easier way but I'm new to this.)

I'm using classes as there will be many of the same image boxes so I'm trying to use :eq to select the second child of each class but I'm getting no where.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: The _easiest_ way is to use `toggleClass`. **Answer:** `$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".drop-box").click(function () { $(".drop-box:eq(2)").removeClass('contracted').toggleClass("drop contract"); }); });`

Comment: There is no need of two `ready` and two event handlers on the same element. Both the handlers will run when the event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".drop-box").click(function() {
    $(".drop-box:eq(1)").removeClass("drop");
    $(".drop-box:eq(1)").addClass("contract");
  });
});
```

```css
.drop-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px
}
.drop-box-title {} .drop-image-box {
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.image-box-text,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
.contracted {
  height: 0px
}
@-webkit-keyframes drop {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
.drop {
  height: auto;
  -webkit-animation-name: drop;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-name: drop;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes contract {
  0% {
    height: 300px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0px;
  }
}
.contract {
  height: 0px;
  -webkit-animation-name: contract;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-name: contract;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="drop-box">
    <div class="drop-box-title">
      <h2>Image Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="drop-image-box contracted">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="drop-box-description">
      <p class="image-box-text">A breif Description of the image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="drop-box">
    <div class="drop-box-title">
      <h2>Image Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="drop-image-box contracted">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="drop-box-description">
      <p class="image-box-text">A breif Description of the image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="drop-box">
    <div class="drop-box-title">
      <h2>Image Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="drop-image-box contracted">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="drop-box-description">
      <p class="image-box-text">A breif Description of the image</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Updated code he need second element so i have change `$(".drop-box:eq(1)").removeClass("drop")`